# GPS Платформа на C# .NET Compac Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, gps, windows-ce

Нужен пример реализации карты на C# Compcat Framework.
Не могу понять как лучше сделать рисовать карту в режиме реального времени или же подставлять картинки, есть предложения?

Answer (score 1):

Если будете рисовать карту в режиме реального времени - несколько советов.

- Храните в модели данных границы каждого объекта (minX, maxX, minY, maxY) и рисуйте только те объекты, которые попадают в видимую область, определяя это по границам.
- Используйте прямоугольную проекцию для работы с картами больших площадей - Меркатора или Голля. Для карты мира лучше подходит проекция Меркатора, для карты России - Голля. Красивее всего смотрится азимутальная проекция, но с ней Вы запаритесь пересчитывать экранные координаты в географические и наоборот.
- Сделайте две фазы загрузки картографических данных: на первой фазе определяете идентификаторы объектов, попадающих в видимую область, на второй - получаете сами объекты с сохранением в кэш. Кэш должен иметь вид словаря, сопоставляющего идентификатору объекта его геометрию и стиль.
- Сделайте дополнительное кэширование уже отрендеренного изображения в Bitmap. При изменении видимой на карте области местности сначала рендерите новый битмап, потом его подменяйте. При перемещении центра карты просто двигайте битмап, перерисовку вызывайте после отпускания кнопки мыши.
- Если предполагается редактирование объектов на карте пользователем, то объект, выделенный для редактирования, в основной битмап попадать не должен, его нужно перерисовывать при каждом вызове OnPaint, чтобы обрабатывать плавное перетаскивание.

С растровыми картами не работал.

Comment: Я уже подобное сделал. Есть ли готовые наработки с красивым дизайном? купим не дорого)

Comment: Нет. Это выдержки из результатов проектирования того, что мы планируем сделать, когда откажемся от MapXtreme. Так что, скорее, может, мы у вас :) Раз у вас уже что-то написано в этом направлении.